# How can I test Unity 8 on the desktop?

Tags: unity, mir

How can I run Unity 8 full-screen running Mir natively like in this video:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E9AzRxsnfTE

Thanks.

Comment: Try use this instruction on OMGUbuntu: http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2013/08/unity-8-ubuntu-13-10-arrives

Comment: That's to just run it on top of the current DE only, isn't it? I mean to run Unity 8 alone.

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to the Software Center (eg. hit the Windows key, type in "Software Center" in the Dash, and click on the icon labelled "Software Center").
2. Click in the search bar in the Software Center and type "unity8 desktop"
3. Click on the search result labeled "Unity8 desktop session for Mir" and select "Install"
4. When it's finished installing, log out and then select "Unity 8" as your session from the LightDM prompt.
5. Log in to your Unity 8 desktop.  Enjoy.

Mir will not work with proprietary video drivers, so be forewarned.

Answer (score 0):

Here's is a guide from unity.ubuntu.com:

https://unity.ubuntu.com/getinvolved/development/unity8/